# No page number for divider pages in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I have a report in LaTeX, and i have used the following commands to create my Appendix, however, my lecturer states that any divider pages should be unnumbered.

```
\documentclass{report}
   \usepackage{appendix}
   \begin{document}
       \include{chap1}
       \include{appendix}
   \end{document}
```

Then in appendix.tex

```
\appendix
\pagestyle{empty}
\appendixpage
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc
```

This creates the `Appendices` divider page, but still puts a page number on it in the footer. There is no page number in the TOC, as expected.

How can I remove it from the footer?

Comment: More two more elegant solutions to this problem are given here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37357/no-page-number-on-appendixpage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the appendix.sty source, and I see the problem: line 74, in the definition of `\@chap@pppage`, issues a `\thispagestyle{plain}` command, thus overriding your `\pagestyle{empty}` for this page.  The inelegant but direct way to fix this is to redefine the command without this line - issue the following code after importing the package.

**Revised, tested version**

```
\documentclass{report}
   \usepackage{appendix}
%==== The action ================
\makeatletter
\def\@chap@pppage{%
  \clear@ppage
  \if@twocolumn\onecolumn\@tempswatrue\else\@tempswafalse\fi
  \null\vfil
  \markboth{}{}%
  { \centering \interlinepenalty \@M
    \normalfont \Huge \bfseries \appendixpagename\par}%
  \if@dotoc@pp\addappheadtotoc\fi
  \vfil\newpage
  \if@twoside
    \if@openright \null \thispagestyle{empty}\newpage\fi
  \fi
  \if@tempswa \twocolumn\fi
}
\makeatother
%==== Back to the document ========
   \begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Blah}
Rhubarb, rhubarb, rhubarb.

\appendix
\pagestyle{empty}
\appendixpage
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc
\chapter{Boff}
Cabbages, cabbages, cabbages.

   \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it still has page numbers on it. I can see the logic of the code, but can't understand why it doesnt work. Thanks.

Comment: @joec: There was a stray "}" in the code I gave.  I've revised & tested the code, and posted the now working fragment.

Answer (score 1):

The [TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=emptynum) might come in handy here:

> **I asked for “empty”, but the page is numbered**
>
> If you use \pagestyle{empty} and you
>   find some pages are numbered anyway,
>   you are probably encountering one of
>   the style decisions built into the
>   standard LaTeX classes: that certain
>   special pages should always appear
>   with \pagestyle{plain}, with a page
>   number at the centre of the page foot.
>   The special pages in question are
>   those (in article class) containing a
>   \maketitle, or (in book and report
>   classes) \chapter or \part commands.
>
> The simple solution is to reissue the
>   page style after the command, with
>   effect for a single page, as, for
>   example (in article):
>
> ```
> \maketitle
> \thispagestyle{empty}
> ```

So give adding `\thispagestyle{empty}` after your `\appendix` a try.

Comment: Just tried that, with no success. I put it after `\appendix` and tried it after `\appendixpage` too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `\pagestyle{empty}` to `\thispagestyle{empty}` and put it after `\addappheadtotoc`.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{appendices} \newpage
\clearpage 

\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\addtocounter{page}{100}
\tableofcontents 
\newpage
```

*Special thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6639/removing-page-numbers-but-not-headers!

Comment: This lacks the flexibility inherent to a LaTeX document since you have to specify the page counters.